# How to prove overdispersion in Poisson regression?

Tags: references, poisson-distribution, overdispersion

For $Y_i$ independent $ \sim \mathcal{Poisson}(λ_i)$, $i = 1, \dotsc,n$, I want to assume $λ_i$ has mean $λ$ and variance $σ^2$. With this I want to show the following, but I am not sure how to show it. All of the websites I've checked, it's simply just been "this is the case", but it doesn't give an explanation why or how and I would like to understand.

[image]

If you have any links to websites that may help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Lots of similar questions with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=poisson+test*+overdispersion+answers%3A1). Must be a dup in there ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I looked through and did not find a duplicate to my question. Most have to do with finding overdispersion in R, which is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I will only give a hint, the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) is your friend. Start out with
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
\V Y = \V\left( \sum_i Y_i\right) =\\
\E \V \sum_i Y_i \mid \lambda_i + \V \E \sum_i Y_i \mid \lambda_i = \dotsm 
$$